# what am i doing wrong/ trying to run MIPS program to construct/draw a box

Tags: assembly, mips

Here is the MIPS program i've written. But my program won't construct/draw a box.

```
.data
 button:   .struct
 xleft:    .byte    0
 ytop:     .byte    0
 size:     .byte    0
 state:    .byte    0
 label:    .space   4
 action:   .word

           .data
 box:      .struct
 ulc:      .byte
 top:      .byte
 urc:      .byte
 left:     .byte
 right:    .byte
 llc:      .byte
 bottom:   .lrc

           .data
 pressed:  .byte 201,205,184,186,174,211,196,217 #ASCII codes for program

 drawBox(box *a0,byte left,byte top, size a3);

           .code
 drawBox:  addi  $sp,$sp,-1
           sw    $a0,($sp)
           sw    $a1,4($sp)
           addi  $t0,$a3,0xf
           srl   $t9,$a3,4
           move  $$a0,$a1
           move  $a1,$a2
           syscall $xy
           lw $t7,($sp)
           syscall $print_char
           lbu $a0,box.top($t7)
           move $t1,$t8
           b     2f

 1:        syscall $print_char
           addi $t1,$t1,-1

 2:        bnez $t1,1b
           lbu $a0,box.urc($t7)
           syscall $print_char
           move $t1,$t9
           b     2f
           syscall $print_char
           addi    

 99:       addi $sp,$sp,8
           jr   $ra
```

Comment: What are you doing wrong? For a start, with every problem report, you should include expected _and_ actual behaviour :-)

Answer (score 2):

This program is full of errors - syntax errors and otherwise. The `.lrc` following `bottom:` looks like it's a variable name from the following line that got accidentally moved up during editing. The `drawBox(box *a0,...)`  isn't valid MIPS assembly syntax either - looks like it was intended to be a comment, but you forgot the `#`. The stack frame setup code (`addi $sp,$sp,-1`) misaligns the stack pointer and will cause the stores to fail (interestingly, the stack frame restore code following label `99:` looks OK). There's other errors as well.

The whole program looks like it was copy & pasted together from several different sources with absolutely no understanding of MIPS assembly language, and the problem sounds like a homework assignment. Try your hands at a simpler program first (add a couple integers together, then write a simple loop, then write a function to print a zero-terminated string, something like that) - it's fairly obvious that you're out of your depth with this problem right now.

Comment: I tried making these changes to my program but it still won't run.

Comment: As said, there's more problems in the source code provided (e.g. the `move $$a0, $a1` which is one $ too much and the free-standing `addi` without any operands after the last `syscall`), but you still haven't explained what's actually going wrong ("it doesn't work" doesn't cut it), and neither have you precisely stated what the intended behavior is (draw a box? As ASCII art, or do you have some sort of video RAM? If so, where?). You also haven't explained what you're running the code on (the syscalls look like SPIM, but that doesn't mean much).